# Characteristic classes of spinor bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, spin-geometry

Given a spin structure on a oriented Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, a spinor is a section of the spinor bundle $\pi:\mathbf{S}\to M$. I am trying to calculate the characteristic classes of the spinor bundle, in particular when $M$ is a 4-manifold.

In this case, the Dold-Whitney theorem says that bundles over $M^4$ are classified topologically by the second Stiefel-Whitney class and the first Pontryagin class. Note that the space of metrics on $M$ is convex (and hence contractible), so all spinor bundles on $M$ are isomorphic.

I am particularly interested in the cases of $S^4$ and a K3 surface. $S^4$ has no second cohomology, so the second Stiefel-Whitney class is trivial. The first Pontryagin class $p_1(\mathbf{S})\in H^4(S^4;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ will correspond to some integer, but I'm not sure which one.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't have an answer to this yet but it is also on my mind.  Let me just mention here that not all spinor bundles on $M$ are necessarily isomorphic: one should not talk about "the" spinor bundle.  One uniqueness result is that if $H^2(M,\mathbb Z)$ has no 2-torsion then spinor bundles associated to spin structures are unique up to iso (see Friedrich, Dirac Operators in Riemannian Geometry, sec. 2.5).  Otherwise there can be as many different spinor bundles as 2-torsion elements in $H^2$, all while keeping the metric fixed.

Comment: @ToddN Don't you mean  $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ ? E.g. $M = S^1$ has essentially two spin structures, but $H^2(S^1,\mathbb{Z}) = 0$. (Similar for $T^n = (S^1)^n$)

Answer (score 1):

For the complex spinor bundle $\textbf{S} \to M^{2n}$ you can prove using the splitting principle, that
$$ ch(\textbf{S}) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i/2} + e^{-x_i/2}$$
where the $x_i$ are Chern roots for $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$. See e.g. in "The Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem" by P. Shanahan page 55 and following.
For $n=2$ this can be spelled out (in degree 2 and 4)
\begin{align*}
c_1(\textbf{S}) &= 0\\
\frac{c_1(\textbf{S})^2}{2}-c_2(\textbf{S}) &= \frac{1}{2}p_1(TM)
\end{align*}
So you have $c_2(\textbf{S}) = -\frac{1}{2}p_1(TM)$. After integration this becomes an integer. For the sphere it is zero and for the $K3$ surface it should be $-24$. Using that $16 = \mathrm{sign}(K3) = \frac{1}{3}\int_{K3} p_1(TK3)$.